# Nvidia drivers debian wheezy

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia

I had some problems with my graphics card.

I tried following the instructions from here
 https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers to install
the appropriate drivers.

The result is I can't start the X server now getting the error message:

```
Fatal server error: no screens found
```

Comment: Have you tried running `nvidia-xconfig`?

Comment: Did you disable Nouveau kernel modesetting? If not, the issue is may be the conflict between nouveau and nvidia modesetting. The nouveau driver IIRC used kernel modesetting since day one, and is included in Wheezy.

Comment: @DanL4096 I am not really sure how to do this...

Comment: @orestiss this could be done by blacklisting the nouveau module, or by adding 'nomodeset' to the kernel boot parameters in GRUB. However I'm not certain that's the problem, now that I think of it; I believe the nVidia drivers are currently supposed to do that on installation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your correct driver defined in:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf

Driver      "Your Driver"